# Converting char* memory address to void* and back in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory

I'm trying to pass a char*'s memory address as a void* , then to convert the void * memory address back to a string somewhere else. So I have,

```
char *text               // text="somestring";
void *memadrs=&text;
```

now I'm trying to convert from the void *memadrs to a new char *.

I apologize if there are other topics concerning this already, but with my searches and confusion regarding pointers/referencing them I could not find anything relevant enough to satisfy this.

Cheers for the help!

edit: Sorry for the confusion folks, the char* isn't a constant.

Comment: `void *` pointer can be casted to or from any type without any problem , no problem in that .  But its not quite clear what you are asking ?

Comment: Regarding the memadrs variable, I'm reading from a pipe and having that value written through. It's pre-determined to be initialized as     
    *memadrs=&text;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given `const char* text = "somestring"`, you really should cast to `const void*` using `const void* memadrs = text`. This is because `"somestring"` is a *read-only* null-terminated string literal. Note that you don't need to use the address-of operator `&` since `text` is already a pointer type.

Using a `const void*` cast helps the emission of compile-time errors if a subsequent cast to `char*` is attempted. This is useful since the behaviour behaviour on casting `memadrs` to a `char*` and then *modifying* the memory would be *undefined* since the original memory is read-only.

A C standard reference to back this up:

> [C99: 6.7.3/5]: If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with
>   a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with
>   non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.

To cast back to a `const char*`, use `(const char*)memadrs`.

My switching of `char const*` to `const char*` is simply personal taste.

Answer (score 2):

You could do :

```
char const *text = "someString";
void *memadrs = text;
char const *newText = memadrs;
```

It should do the work by making implicit cast.

With explicit cast it look like :

```
char const *text = "someString";
void *memadrs = (void*)text;
char const *newText = (char const *)memadrs;
```

Answer (score 1):

Any non-function pointer can be automatically converted to a `void *` and back without casting.

In your example, you're trying to copy the address of `char *`, (i.e. a `char **`) to a `void *`, which is probably not what you want.  You probably want this:

```
char  const *text="somestring";
void *memadrs=text;
```

Comment: You may get a compiler warning about discarding the `const` qualifier if you do that though. To avoid such a warning, you'd either need to do `const void *memadrs=text;` or `void *memadrs=(void *)text;`, the second option being the more dangerous!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a pointer to a pointer. I suspect that you want a pointer with the same value that `text`. So you could do

```
void *memadrs = text; // without &
```